# find_nearest_contour is deprecated. Now what?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, deprecation-warning

I'm using Matplotlib contours to explore a 2d map. I'm using [`contour.find_nearest_contour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourSet.find_nearest_contour) to get the range of x and y of the contour that passes close to a point `x0, y0`, as follows:

```py
cs = fig.gca().contour(x, y, image, [level])

cont, seg, idx, xm, ym, d2 = cs.find_nearest_contour(x0, y0, pixel=False)

min_x = cs.allsegs[cont][seg][:, 0].min()
max_x = cs.allsegs[cont][seg][:, 0].max()
min_y = cs.allsegs[cont][seg][:, 1].min()
max_y = cs.allsegs[cont][seg][:, 1].max()
```

> cont, seg, idx, xm, ym, d2 = cs.find_nearest_contour(x0, y0, pixel=False)

Now Matplotlib v3.8 is throwing a `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning`, but I can't find any document that explains how to get the same functionality.

Note that a given contour level can create multiple segments, and I also need what segment is closer to my point. I need `seg` in my line of code, practically. This is not shared from the private method `_find_nearest_contour` which was a very good candidate for replacement.

Comment: Matplotlib seems to have been a bit overzealous in deprecations there.  Internal representation of contours changed, so some public interface was modified.  Please see, and comment at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27070

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak, I commented there

Answer (score 1):

- Continue using `.find_nearest_contour` until it's removed.
- Based on this [comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27070#issuecomment-1760278256) in [matplotlib issue 27070](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27070), the private method, `._find_nearest_contour`, can be used until, or if, a public method is reimplemented.

  - > It was deprecated because the old return value, ..., doesn't really make much sense for the new internal representation of [`ContourSets`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourSet:%7E:text=class%20matplotlib.contour.ContourSet) (there's a single Collection, and a single path per level)
  - If you have existing code, you will probably need to do one of the following:

    - Continue using matplotlib less then 3.8
    - Use the newest implementation and update your code with respect to the new `Returns`
- Given the sample code:

  - `CS.find_nearest_contour(0, 0)` → `(5, 0, 296, 209.70308429471964, 168.30113207547168, 72300.65462060366)`
  - `CS._find_nearest_contour((0, 0))` → `(5, 296, array([209.70308429, 168.30113208]))`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

# Basic contour plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)

CS._find_nearest_contour((0, 0))  # private method
```

[image]

```py
Signature: CS._find_nearest_contour(xy, indices=None)
Docstring:
Find the point in the unfilled contour plot that is closest (in screen
space) to point *xy*.

Parameters
----------
xy : tuple[float, float]
    The reference point (in screen space).
indices : list of int or None, default: None
    Indices of contour levels to consider.  If None (the default), all levels
    are considered.

Returns
-------
idx_level_min : int
    The index of the contour level closest to *xy*.
idx_vtx_min : int
    The index of the `.Path` segment closest to *xy* (at that level).
proj : (float, float)
    The point in the contour plot closest to *xy*.
File:      c:\users\trenton\anaconda3\envs\py312\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py
Type:      method
```

### Regarding Private Methods

- [Is it bad practice NOT to use private methods and functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66694081/7758804)
- [Private methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17193457/7758804)
- [Why are Python's 'private' methods not actually private?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70528/7758804)

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to specify that I actually need the nearest path created by the contour, which is not returned by `_find_nearest_contour`.
Also, pinning to Matplotlib <=3.8 is not feasible for us, so either Matplotlib creates an alternative method, or I will need to change strategy completely.

Comment: @matteo Since the API was changed, it's not likely `matplotlib` will return to the previous functionality, even if they introduce a new public method. Your other option is to reintroduce the `contour.find_nearest_contour` [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.0/lib/matplotlib/contour.py#L1394-L1472) in your local repository.